# Remove variable from autocomplete - version 10 issue?

Tags: front-end, autocomplete, version-10

I've got a program that's fairly long.  Occasionally I ClearAll some lists that I created.  That works fine, but those lists continue to show up in the autocomplete.  Is there anyway to remove them from the autocomplete?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Remove`

```
aber = {1, 2, 3}

Remove@aber
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work.  I just upgraded to version 10, maybe that's why?

Comment: @MitchellKaplan Works perfectly with me ("9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 25, 2013)") Documentation: "Remove removes symbols completely, so that their names are no longer recognized by Mathematica."

Comment: I have a machine with version 9 on it, and you're right, it does work on version 9.  It doesn't on version 10!  Weird.

Comment: @MitchellKaplan bug verified in my instance of MMA10, Win7 (64Bit)

Comment: @PatoCriollo bug or feature?

Comment: Was this solved in 10.1 or 10.2? I can't reproduce it but I am having problems with the autocomplete information not refreshing (when I change it in a package) even after quitting the kernel.